# How to view output table in R Shiny?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to add my output table to my ui.R.

I have:

In Server:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable)({
data <- data.table(redactedColumnName = redactedVariableName)
data })
```

In ui:

```
DT::dataTableOutput("table")
```

The error I receive is

> Error: "Expecting a single string value: [type=character, extent = 0].

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Take a look at [this page](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) for examples of the correct syntax for `renderDataTable`.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed my code but I am now stuck trying to figure out where to assign "data" as it needs the variables from a different render session than the output$tbl render session.

Comment: try `output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({data.table(my_table) })` or just `output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ my_table })`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm now having an issue where it cannot find my object "data" (which is my table name) as it is in a different render UI session (it uses variables from that session)